# Is it possible to run two servers on a same system simultaneously? Or how can I execute a MySQL query in Eclipse while XAMPP/WAMP is not running?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, webserver, eclipse-luna

I have **two questions**, for those which I did not get any solution sounds good for my expectations.

**1. Why both XAMPP/WAMP and Apache Tomcat?**

Assume if I am now running a Windows system, with Eclipse LUNA.

Now, **if I have to run a query for my localhost server, how does Eclipse help?**
I won't be satisfied if you say there should be an **XAMPP server** running live for your query to execute in Eclipse(Like they say here [Database Development Using the Eclipse IDE, MySQL with Eclipse Data Tools Platform in Java](http://www.bhaveshthaker.com/33/database-development-using-the-eclipse-ide-mysql-with-eclipse-data-tools-platform-in-java/#Install_Setup)).

Then **why Tomcat is there?**

Sorry if there is some loop hole, or may be this is a Banana-Monkey` type question. All because I don't get it clear.

And now, my second question.

**2. How can I(Is it possible to) run a Java project in Eclipse with Apache Tomcat while WAMP/XAMPP is running in background in my system?**

Suppose I am on the same system working with different user privileges. Say *user1* runs both the **XAMPP** and **Eclipse** *As Administrator*. Now (or anyhow) is it possible to run a project in Apache Tomcat while WAMP/XAMPP is running in background simultaneously in the system?

I am totally confused. Helps with your comments and answers are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If there are two questions then they should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run two servers on same system simultaneously.

Yes you can execute a MySQL query when XAMP/WAMP is not running.

It seems you don't understand your setup and the elements involved.

XAMP/WAMP contains Apache server, so a http server that can handle static html or run php scripts. It also comes with a MySQL database.

So the only important part from the Java WebAPP is the MySQL. You can start MySQL without starting apache, you can finally install MySQL yourself (it has simple windows installer). But if your application is using MySQL it has to be running for it to work (be it a XAMP version or standalone version).

Your Java Web Application requires application container to run, and it is the Tomcat. It is Apache Tomcat as it is developed under apache groupe, but it is not the same as Apache web server.

So you need tomcat to run your web app. Again you can install one yourself or use the one that comes toghether with Eclipse.

You can have many tomcats at the same time, all running (for example different version of Tomcats or Java) as long as they listen on different ports. The ports on which tomcat is runing is configured in its server.xml file under conf directory.